# Serenity-BDD: Screenplay: How to find a string of text anywhere on the page (in any element)

Tags: serenity-bdd

After searching for a few hours, I have to ask...

I want to be find a string of text on a page. Specifically, I'm looking to ensure the proper errors are displayed based on a user's form submission. Given that there could be several messages, and the web application I'm dealing with, if I could capture each element into a list I think I could iterate over the list and match strings.

Serenity-BDD is new to me and I'm digging Screenplay (and my boss loves the reporting) but I'm finding it hard to wrap my head around some of it (and good walk-through examples are few). Additionally, I have very little experience with Selenium either.

If anyone could help, or point me to some information (besides the serenity-bdd online manual) I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the screenplay pattern you write Questions which return your form errors which can be checked in your BDD tests. For example I have a Form which shows the errors next to the input value. All errors have the css class ".text-danger".
A matching `Question` object would look like this:

```
public class FormErrors
 implements Question<List<String>> {

 public static FormErrors displayed() {
    return new FormErrors();
 }

 @Override
 public List<String> answeredBy( Actor actor ) {
    return Text.of( EnterForm.FORM_ERRORS ).viewedBy( actor ).asList();
 }
}
```

The `FORM_ERRORS` constant looks like this:

```
public static final Target FORM_ERRORS = Target.the( "Form Errors" ).locatedBy( ".text-danger" );
```

So I am able to check for the correct errors like this:

```
theActorInTheSpotlight().should( 
  seeThat( FormErrors.displayed(), is( errors ) ) 
);
```

A good example how to write screenplay tests is the [screenplay-pattern-todomvc](https://github.com/serenity-bdd/screenplay-pattern-todomvc) project.